# render ejs template for robots.txt in express

Tags: node.js, express, robots.txt

I want to use some variables in my robots.txt file in Express.

How can I render this file as an EJS template? I already have EJS working for .html files.

```
app.route('/robots.txt')
    .get(index.robotstxt);


/**
 * Send robotstxt file
 */
exports.robotstxt = function (req, res) {
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.render('robots.txt', {
        home: config.home
    });
};


# robotstxt.org

User-agent: *
Disallow: /settings
Disallow: /account/
Allow: /

sitemap: <%= home %>/sitemap.xml
```

Currently, I just get the the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'txt' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15) at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25) at Module.require (module.js:364:17) at require (module.js:380:17) at new View (/Users/user/projects/app/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:43:49) at Function.app.render (/Users/user/projects/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:484:12) at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/user/projects/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:777:7) at Object.exports.robotstxt [as handle] (/Users/user/projects/app/lib/controllers/index.js:29:6) at next_layer (/Users/user/projects/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13) at Route.dispatch (/Users/user/projects/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
```

The template is in `./app/views/robots.txt`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working by moving `./app/robots.txt` to `./app/views/robots.ejs`

```
/**
 * Send robotstxt file
 */
exports.robotstxt = function (req, res) {
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.render('robots.ejs', { //use .ejs extension instead of .txt
        home: config.home
    });
};
```

Comment: i think the url that google looks is /robots.txt, so this would not be the correct solution.

Comment: The resource is robots.txt

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue, the solution I found is to use the npm module [express-robots-txt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-robots-txt).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31577117)

Answer (score -1):

You should render xml sitemap in the ejs file

```
app.route('/robots.txt').get(index.robotstxt);

exports.robotstxt = function (req, res) {
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.render('robots.ejs', {
        home: config.home
    });
};
```

In that way, your file robots.ejs will contain xml data and you will be able to see it ad [www.yoursite.com/sitemap.xml](http://www.yoursite.com/sitemap.xml)

Comment: robots.txt is text content.

Comment: You can render txt text content in the ejs file as I did in the above example

Comment: right but its not xml so why use incorrect content-type?

Comment: You're right, I got it now, I am going to edit the above code with res.type('text/plain');

Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Then you're just copying my answer

Comment: I did not, as you can see the code it's different, as well as I added the code when I fixed the issue on my app

Comment: I don’t see any difference